# How to work in php page with more mysql database connections in real-time

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I have three mysql databases with same structure (same tables). Then I have one query, that return different results from each database.

I want have one php page, where I will have radiobutton, listbox, etc. (without submit button), where I will choose database (DB1/DB2/DB3) and then I will see the results according to the selected database (I want it in real-time, without submit button).

What I have:

index.php

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    </head>

    <?php
    include_once ('connection_db_1.php');
    ?>

    <body>
        <form action="">
            <select name="database">
                <option value="DB1">DB1</option>
                <option value="DB2">DB2</option>
                <option value="DB3">DB3</option>
            </select>
        </form>


    <?php
    include ('queries.php');
    $test_1 = mysqli_query($mysqli_db, $test);
    echo "
                    <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Column_1</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>";

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($test_1)) {
        echo "<form method=\"post\"><tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['Column_1'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr></form>";
    }
    echo "</table><br>";
    mysqli_close($mysqli_db);
    ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

queries.php

```
<?php
$test = "select Column_1 from TEST; ";
?>
```

connection_db_1.php

```
<?php
// Connection data
$servername = "servename";
$username = "username";
$password = "pasword";
$dbname = "dbname_1";

// Create connection
$mysqli_db = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($mysqli_db->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $mysqli_db->connect_error);
}
?>
```

connection_db_2.php

```
<?php
// Connection data
$servername = "servename";
$username = "username";
$password = "pasword";
$dbname = "dbname_2";

// Create connection
$mysqli_db = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($mysqli_db->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $mysqli_db->connect_error);
}
?>
```

I think, that I need some javascript/ajax solution, but I dont know how use it effectively.

Thank you for some advice.

Comment: The simplest method is to reload the full page after you select your db.

Comment: So you just want to learn how to do ajax?

Comment: I would split up your problem into smaller subproblems: 1) Form submission 2) Selecting database based on form field 3) Further improvements such as AJAX, if needed/desired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per now I can't see you showing any examples where you use or have implemented any ajax handler.
I could suggest you use either plain Javascript or jQuery (by including a javascript library, [see her](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

What you could do, before considering implementing AJAX, is the following (it will include the database after first selection and form submission):

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["database"])) {
    $db = $_POST["database"];
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
</head>

<?php
include_once("connection_db_" . $db . ".php"); /* This will include the selected connection */
?>

<body>
<form action="" method="post">
    <select name="database">
        <option value="1">DB1</option>
        <option value="2">DB2</option>
        <option value="3">DB3</option>
    </select>
</form>


<?php
include('queries.php');
$test_1 = mysqli_query($mysqli_db, $test);
echo "
                    <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Column_1</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>";

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($test_1)) {
    echo "<form method=\"post\"><tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Column_1'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr></form>";
}
echo "</table><br>";
mysqli_close($mysqli_db);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for solution, I did it like you propose, but I dont know, how to use javascript so I don't have to use submit button. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Are the databases on the same server? If so, you only need one connection to the server. You can make the query by adding the database name in the query:

```
select Column_1 from dbname_1.TEST
```

or

```
select Column_1 from dbname_2.TEST
```